# SP 2010: JSOM function not working on page load

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, jsom, updatelistitems

I am running a function on page load to update list item. Here's my complete code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    updatePageViewCount();
});
function updatePageViewCount() {
    var clContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var topicList = clContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Topics');
    clContext.load(topicList);
    clContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFail));
}

function onQuerySuccess() {
    var listItemEnum = topicList.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
       var topicListItem = listItemEnum.get_current();
       var url = window.location.href;
       alert(url);
       var topicId = url.split("ID=")[1].split("&")[0];
       alert(topicId);
       if(topicListItem.get_Item('Topic_x0020_ID') == topicId){
           var oldData = topicListItem.get_item('ViewCount');
           var newData = parseInt(oldData) + 1;
           alert(newData);
           topicListItem.set_item('ViewCount', newData);
           topicListItem.update();
           clContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onItemUpdated), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFail));  
      }
   }
 }

 function onItemUpdated() {
       alert('Item has been updated!');
 }

 function onQueryFail(sender, args) {
       alert('Request failed.');
 }
```

Can anyone help me find a fix for this?

Comment: What is the problem? What does or does not work?

Comment: I am unable to read the list item and make an update.

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: It's not throwing any error

Answer (score 3):

make the couple of changes as below.

1. Use `ExecuteorDelayUntilScriptLoaded` to make sure you are executing logic after sp.js file loaded.
2. Your `topLists` variable make it global as you are using in other function.

Make the corrections as shown below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updatePageViewCount, "sp.js");
});
var topicList
function updatePageViewCount() {
    var clContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    topicList = clContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Topics');
    clContext.load(topicList);
    clContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFail));
}

function onQuerySuccess() {
    //topicList is an object. so try to put some alert like this.
    alert(topicList.Title);
}
```

Comment: I made the corrections as you suggested. But, it did not work. What am I doing wrong? I also tried to run the function on a button click. That too did not work.

Comment: check your browser console to see if there are errors in the scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Running your code yields an error: `topicList.getEnumerator()` is not possible, as `topicList` is an `SP.List` and thus, no function `getEnumerator` is available.

If you incorporate the answer from Venkat Konjeti and additionally modify your `topicsList` to:

```
topicList = clContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Topics').getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
```

it should work. At least I'm getting your `alert(url)`-messages. That is only if the list "Topics" exists and has at least one item.

Comment: After modifying the code I'm now able to read only the first item in the list. I've added a alert inside the while loop. It's only checking the first item. here's my code (added my comments for the alerts) - https://jsfiddle.net/np0j9Lop/

Comment: try adding the columns (`Topic_x0020_ID` and `ViewCount`) as includes in the load like so: `context.load(topicList, 'Topic_x0020_ID,ViewCount');`

Comment: I'm calling the load method without any additional parameter. So, it's loading all columns in the list. And I'm able to alert these two column's values for an item. But the if condition is still failing.

Comment: I updated the code again. Now, I'm able to see the updated value after set_item operation inside if statement, but it's not getting saved in the list. Update method is failing. My code https://jsfiddle.net/np0j9Lop/5/

Answer (score 2):

This could be because your function is called even before loading SP.js file. Try updating your code by using the Script On Demand method call as :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',updatePageViewCount);
});
```

This way your main function will run only after SP.js load.

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti - Nope. It works in SP 2010 as well. Check MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: More over the best practise is Execute Function and not ExecuteorDelayUntilScriptLoaded as the later will cause an indefinite lock and never call the call back function if SP.js is not loaded . 
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/key-points-to-know-when-using-sp-sod-executefunc-and-sp-sod-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded/

Comment: deleted my comment. But will try this.

Comment: @Priyan It does not work for me. Alternately, I tried to run the function on button click. It also failed.

Comment: Try putting debugger/alert in your code and let us know what is failing at what point in the code

Comment: The code is failing in the update() method. I'm able to see the updated value in the alert after the set_item operation https://jsfiddle.net/np0j9Lop/5/

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible "SP.js" is not fully loaded when you called your function in document ready function.

Please try below code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', updatePageViewCount);
```

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti - Please dont mislead people. It works quite well even in SP 2010 Foundation .https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx

Also ExecuteFunc is the best practise and not ExecuteOrDelayUntillScriptLoaded 

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/key-points-to-know-when-using-sp-sod-executefunc-and-sp-sod-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded/

Comment: Deleted my comment. But will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is almost a one year old question, but it might help others too.

If you are using Internet Explorer, and the loaded page URL contains **#** like in http://sharepoint/_layouts/start.aspx?#/sitepages/home.aspx you should read about MDS (Minimal Download Strategy). This blocks your JavaScript what is not registered with RegisterModuleInit() function.

Here is a good article:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site/

Deactivating MDS could also help.